# Fedora проблемы с установкой - определяет 2 монитора

Tags: fedora

Бьюсь с установкой Fedora (в данном случае -18, но с 17 те же проблемы). Устанавливаю на неттоп от Foxconn. Видео встроенное, процессор Intel Atom 3500, установка с LiveCD или LiveDVD, монитор Acer x243W. Fedora считает, что в системе 2 монитора( хотя даже физически выход у видеокарты 1). ПРи этом по умолчанию этот монитор воспринимается как дополнительный, соотвественно меню недоступно. Вот что выдает команда **xrandr**

```
[root@localhost ~]# xrandr --current    
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3280 x 1200, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm       
   1360x768       60.0*+
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9      
VGA1 connected 1920x1200+1360+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm       
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0   
   1440x900       75.0     59.9
   1280x800       74.9     59.8 
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3 
   640x480        75.0     60.0 
   720x400        70.1     
 [root@localhost ~]#
```

Когда подключаю монитор 1280x1024 - попадаю в рабочее окно с меню, но xrandr  также показывает что в системе 2 монитора. Смотрел BIOS - там даже пункта настроек VGA или чего-то связанного с видео, нет. Debian и Ubuntu устанавливаются без проблем. Один раз получилось поставить Fedora 18, (не обратил вниманию на манипуляции и не забэкапил - теперь жалею) потом пришлось снести из-за косяков Гнома. Как это побороть на этапе установки или после нее. Если устанавливаю MATE, то потом могу открыть окно терминала и оключить LVDS1, но настройки не сохраняются. Пытался прописать команду:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
```

в файл `~/.xprofile`, но при перезагрузке происходит то же самое.

Answer (score 1):

А если прибить при загрузке ядра? В /boot/grub/grub.conf в строчку c linux или kernel добавить параметр:

```
 video=LVDS-1:d
```

Comment: Не помогло. :( Пока вышел из положения так:Alt+F2 - открывается список программ, выбираю "Мониторы" и отключаю паразитный монитор "Ноутбук", применяю настройки. Это явный баг - отправлю репорт в Bugzilla

Comment: ещё нашёл на убунтуфоруме:/etc/X11/Xsession.d/ создать файл "45custom_xrandr-settings":    EXTERNAL_OUTPUT="VGA"    INTERNAL_OUTPUT="LVDS"    xrandr |grep $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT | grep " connected "    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then        xrandr --output $INTERNAL_OUTPUT --off --output $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT --auto     else        xrandr --output $INTERNAL_OUTPUT --auto --output $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT --off    fi

Comment: 17-18 Fedora  не примут баги. Они уже давно не поддерживаются.